# URL load error during adding

Tags: java, eclipse

i have a string say Path ="C:\AAA\bin" which is a path to a project's bin folder. I used new URL(Path) during invocation of addURL method of URLClassLoader class.

ex- addURL(sysLoader,new URL(Path)) ;

its giving unknown  protocol:c  exception

whats the problem?Help

Answer (score 1):

you have to use something like this

```
Path="file://C://AAA/bin".
```

Here 'file' refers to the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to tranform your String path into an URL.
The simplest way is to create a `File` from your `String` path, then call its `toURI` method.

in other words :

```
addURL(sysLoader, new File(Path).toURI().toURL());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `new URL(Path)` with `new File(Path).toURL()` and it will work.

Also, don't forget to escape the \ in the file path:

```
"C:\\AAA\\bin"
```